# Unable to populate data on the JTable

Tags: java, swing

I need to populate the data using JTable. I referred few blogs, but still unable to find the reason it's not populated.

From the Java application, creates the below MainFrame

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainFrame customerFrame = new MainFrame();
        customerFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

In this frame it'll load JDialog("CustomerDialog"). When loading the dialog I written the below code to create JTable called **"tblCustomr"** and want to load the table data when loading the **"CustomerDialog"**

```
public CustomerDialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
    super(parent, modal);
    tblCustomer = new JTable(loadTable());
    initComponents();

}

private DefaultTableModel loadTable(){
    String[] columns = {"Customer Id", "Customer Name", "Customer Address"};
    DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    for(String col:columns) {
        tableModel.addColumn(col);
    }

    //tblCustomer.add(tableModel);
    List<Object[]> customers = new CustomerService().getAllCustomers();
    for(Object[] obj: customers) {
        tableModel.addRow(obj);
    }
    return tableModel;
}
```

**"tableModel"** contains both columns and one row. But it didn't show the table records as in the shared image.[image: no_table_record]. Records should visibly above the panel name as "Customer record editor".

Could someone tell me what I have missed here or is this not the correct way of doing this.

I referred this blog "http://www.kode-blog.com/java-swing-jdbc-crud-example-with-jasper-reports"

Comment: You really need to create and post a valid [mcve] for most of us to make heads or tails out of your code and your problem. Please read the link. This means refactoring your code so that you isolate the JTable creation portion by itself, in a stand alone compilable and runnable program, small enough to post in your question in its entirety and that reproduces the problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

```
tblCustomer = new JTable(loadTable());
```

We have no idea if you ever add the table to a JScrollPane and then add the scroll pane to the frame.

```
String[] columns = {"Customer Id", "Customer Name", "Customer Address"};
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
for(String col:columns) {
    tableModel.addColumn(col);
}
```

Don't manually create the columns. You can just use:

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
```

and let the DefaultTableModel do the work for you.

```
for(Object[] obj: customers) {
    tableModel.addRow(obj);
}
```

Did you debug the above code to see if you actually have any data? You could either add a display in the loop to display each row, or after the loop display the row count of the TableModel.